# Plot multiple buffers around points

Tags: polygon, buffer, plot

I have three buffer radius sizes

```
radius<-c(1000,700,500)
```

that I have placed around an array of points (two example points are given [here](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/LD9SO) in the file SourcePlace).

What I'd like to do is visualise the three buffer sizes, in different colours, on the same plot. I `attach` the file with the point information, then

```
install.packages("sp")
library(sp)
PlaceCoord <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data.frame(UTM.Easting,UTM.Northing),data=data.frame(PlaceID,Name,lngYear,IDgroup),proj4string=CRS("+init=epsg:32717"))
ptbufN <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
  ptbufN[i] <- gBuffer(PlaceCoord, width = radius[i], quadsegs = 10)
}
plot(ptbufN[[1]], density=NA, col=1)
plot(ptbufN[[2]], density=NA, col=2)
plot(ptbufN[[3]], density=NA, col=3)
points(PlaceCoord, pch = 20, col = 'red')
```

What I can't seem to fix is that my polygons are drawn on new plots each time. Maybe there's code to add polygons to existing plots somewhere in ggplot2?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure more elegant ways to perform this task, but I have come to a solution. This requires `sp`, `ggplot2`, and `rgeos`.

As before, I `attach`ed the file with the point information.

```
 PlaceCoord <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data.frame(UTM.Easting,UTM.Northing),data=data.frame(PlaceID,Name,lngYear,IDgroup),proj4string=CRS("+init=epsg:32717"))

#Establish the three radii of interest 
radius<-c(1000,700,500)

#Create each of the buffers
ptbuf <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
  ptbuf[i] <- gBuffer(PlaceCoord, width = radius[i], quadsegs = 10)
}
firstbuffer<-ptbuf[[1]]
secondbuffer<-ptbuf[[2]]
thirdbuffer<-ptbuf[[3]]
all_buffers<-list(firstbuffer,secondbuffer,thirdbuffer)



 #plot
    ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = all_buffers[[1]], aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), colour="black", fill="black", alpha=0.45)  + # adds the first plot. colour is for the outline, fill is obvious and alpha sets the transparency (1 = opaque) of the polygon
  geom_polygon(data = all_buffers[[2]], aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), colour="red", fill="red", alpha=0.45) + # adds the second plot
  geom_polygon(data = all_buffers[[3]], aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), colour="green", fill="green", alpha=0.45) + # adds the third plo
  geom_point(data=SourcePlace,aes(x = UTM.Easting, y = UTM.Northing))+
  coord_equal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank())
```

The group parameter under aes helped me eliminate unwanted lines across my polygons, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465040/ggplot2-facet-plot-of-shapefile-polygons-produces-strange-lines). The output plot, with my entire point array included, looks like this:

[image]